# Erlang: erlide syntax highlighting in eclipse ide?

Tags: eclipse, erlang, syntax-highlighting, erlide

I went under window->preferences->erlang (in the tree)->editor->syntax coloring to try changing the syntax coloring, similarly to Java but there is no option for it even though erlide 0.20.2 says it supports it on their [site](http://erlide.org/) (under editor support). I'm using Eclipse Juno and erlide 0.20.3. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "there is no option" -- we had this feature for a very long time. What do you see on that preference page?

The preview doesn't get updated and I see that if you have files open in the editor, they need to be closed and reopened to see the changes. I created a ticket for that, it's indeed confusing.

Comment: Under the syntax coloring page found under the tree erlang->editor->syntax coloring I have box named element with different coloring options for text attributes such as atom, variable, etc.. specific things but nothing about syntax highlighting. I also have four checkboxes in a column for bold, italic, strikeout, underline and a preview window with some sample module. I also checked the tree general->editor and general->appearances and looked for anything that says syntax highlighting and found nothing.

Comment: What do you understand by "syntax highlighting"? It is exactly the process that assigns different styles to different syntactic elements. That page lets you choose the styles.

Comment: No thats not syntax highlighting. Syntax highlighting makes all the words with the same spelling on a source code get "colored" a different color than normal when the word is selected. Thats syntax highlighting. What you are talking about has nothing to do with the question I asked but I marked it correct anyways because you were right about restarting eclipse to make the changes for text coloring go in effect.

Comment: Oh, okay, I see. The Eclipse name for this functionality is "mark occurences" and there is a button for it on the toolbar (a yellow pen thingy) with keyboard shortcut Shift-Alt-O. You might need to disable and reenable it to make it work, we have a ticket for fixing that.

Comment: By the way, with the latest versions the colors get updated right away, no need to restart!